# Usage of QueryResult inside reactive neo4j Spring repository

Tags: neo4j, spring-data, rx-java, reactive

I have the following repository:

```
public interface MessageRepository extends ReactiveNeo4jRepository<Message, Long>, ExtendedMessageRepository
{
    @Query("MATCH(m:Message) WHERE id(m)=$start MATCH(m)-[:PREDECESSOR*1..11]->(message:Message)<-[:SENT]-(user:User) MATCH(m)-[:PREDECESSOR]->(predecessor:Message) RETURN message, user AS sender, predecessor AS predecessor ORDER BY message.timestamp")
    Flux<Message> findPredecessors(long start);
}
```

Basically this repository works and I get the correct amount of message objects. The only problem is that sender and predecessor inside the message objects are null. Am I missing something or is this feature currently not supported for the neo4j-rx repositories?

```
public class Message extends AbstractEntity
{
    private String content;

    private LocalDateTime timestamp;

    @Relationship(type = "SENT", direction = Relationship.Direction.INCOMING)
    private User sender;

    @Relationship(type = "PREDECESSOR", direction = Relationship.Direction.OUTGOING)
    private Message predecessor;

    // getter, setter
}
```